# using openssl dll in setup.py

Tags: openssl, setup.py

I'm trying to include 'openssl 3.0.0. dll' and 'lib' file to setup.py

this is my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
    
setup(
        name='test',
        version='1.0',
        package_data=[r"./crypto/Openssl/bin/libssl-3.dll", r"./crypto/Openssl/bin/libcrypto-3.dll", r"./crypto/Openss/lib/libcrypto.lib", r"./crypto/Openssl/lib/libcrypto.lib"],
        description='test',
        include_dirs = [r'./crypto/Openssl/include', r'./crypto/Openssl/lib', r'./crypto/Openssl/bin'],
        ext_modules=[Extension("test", sources=[r'./example/example_main.cpp'])]
    )
```

and in example_main.cpp I include below headers

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

But when I excute "python setup.py install", then got this error ' error LNK2001 : unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'

I tried to find a solution, but almost time, they recommend to install openssl to computer with internet.

But I want to include compiled openssl dll file, becuase I will install on the computer that don't have internet.

If there is solution, plz help.

(I use python 3.7.2 32 bit with Powershell 64 bit, openssl 3.0.0.dll built with WIN32 configure)

Comment: it solved. I put lib files in same directory with setup.py and finally it works

Comment: but... openssl function still not working